Aplicacion Java JEE que se encuentra desplegada en Weblogic, no está tomando la hora correcta
se tiene una aplicación Java EE desplegada en weblogic, no está tomando la hora correcta, primero la consola de weblogic no tomaban la hora correcta, en el archivo setDomainEnv.sh se agregó JAVA_OPTIONS="${JAVA_OPTIONS}-Duser.timezone=CST-6"
export JAVA_OPTIONS, ya refleja la hora correcta en las consolas del weblogic, pero el de la aplicación desplegada no, ha tenido este problema ? Que me puedan orientar, gracias.
